# D3 js bars renders on top each other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, charts

I'm trying to display stacked barchart but it renders bars on top each other. As I guess the problem with x-axis but can't find out where I'm making mistake

here is sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-wave-s3jvw9?file=/src/styles.css

```
    const xScale = d3
      .scaleBand()
      .domain(data.map((d) => d.date.slice(0, 10)))
      .range([0, width])
      .padding(0.25);

    svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
      .style('color', '#ffffff')
      .selectAll('text')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(15,35)rotate(90)');

    svg
      .selectAll('.layer')
      .data(layers)
      .join('g')
      .attr('class', 'layer')
      .attr('fill', (layer) => colors[layer.key])
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data((layer) => layer)
      .join('rect')
      .attr('x', (sequence) => {
        xScale(sequence.data.date);
      })
      .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
      .attr('y', (sequence) => yScale(sequence[1]))
      .attr('height', (sequence) => yScale(sequence[0]) - yScale(sequence[1]));
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Using React AND Vue here?

Comment: `.attr('x', (sequence) => { *return* xScale(sequence.data.date); })` but you also need to provide the scale the same values you provided to the scale's domain: `xScale(sequence.data.date.slice(0, 10)`. There's still some issues, but those are two things.

Comment: There's actually no Vue code in the reproduction. It only contains React code.